# How to make an update function for an object property?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a list of values in the following form:

```js
interface MyItem<Type> {
    value: Type;
    description: string;
}

interface MyDictionary {
    someNumber: MyItem<number>;
    someString: MyItem<string>;
    truthOrFalsehood: MyItem<boolean>;
}

const myDictionary: MyDictionary = {
    someNumber: {
        value: 1,
        description: "Math",
    },
    someString: {
        value: "abc",
        description: "Language",
    },
    truthOrFalsehood: {
        value: true,
        description: "Philosophy",
    },
};
```

Now, I'd like to make an update function that would know what type to use. I'm not sure how to read the type of the MyItem:

```js
type UpdateFunction = <Type extends keyof MyDictionary>(
    key: Type,
    value: MyDictionary[Type].value, // Can't do that
) => void;

const update: UpdateFunction = (key, value) => {
    myDictionary[key].value = value;
};

update("someNumber", 7); // Should be okay
update("foo", "bar"); // Should throw a compile error
```

I'm not sure how to define the `UpdateFunction` type to connect the `value` property type with what `MyDictionary` expects for that key.

Comment: Are you just looking for [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)?  You write `T["key"]` and not `T.key`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZy6aN).  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining (if I don't find an existing duplicate target); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, it works with `["value"]`, I thought it would be more complex. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: Given that the issue here is essentially "can't do `MyDictionary[Type].value` but *can* do `MyDictionary[Type]["value"]`" I'd say this is mainly asking how to read properties from types at known literal keys, and so the linked questions and answers are appropriate.  Anyone who comes here looking for the answer to this specific question will get their answer by following the links.

Comment: @jcalz okay, cool. I forgot about the `["key"]` syntax in TypeScript to be honest.